# golang future with WaitGroup block forever

Tags: go

I wrote the following code trying to implement future for a group of async jobs. and it works. but I don't understand why I have to wrap `wg.Wait()` in a goroutine w/o it main will block.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "https://www.easyjet.com/",
    "https://www.skyscanner.de/",
    "https://www.ryanair.com",
    "https://wizzair.com/",
    "https://www.swiss.com/",
}

func checker(urls []string) func() chan urlStatus {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    c := make(chan urlStatus)
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go checkUrl(url, c, wg)
    }
    return func() chan urlStatus {
        go func() { // <--- why this goroutine is necessary. change it to sync will block
            wg.Wait()
            close(c)
        }()
        return c
    }
}
func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    
    future := checker(urls)

    go consumer(future(), done)

    <-done
}

func consumer(c <-chan urlStatus, done chan bool) {
    for r := range c {
        if r.status {
            fmt.Println(r.url, "is up.")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(r.url, "is down!!")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("end of consumer")
    done <- true
}

//checks and prints a message if a website is up or down
func checkUrl(url string, c chan<- urlStatus, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    _, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        // The website is down
        c <- urlStatus{url, false}
    } else {
        // The website is up
        c <- urlStatus{url, true}
    }
}

type urlStatus struct {
    url    string
    status bool
}
```

Comment: I think it is because of this line
```
go consumer(future(), done)
```
When future() is called, the main go routine is blocked by wg.Wait()

Comment: @nimdrak I thought checkUrl will drop wg to 0 in the background. did I miss something?

Comment: You miss the channel size. You can see the it works well by declaring `c := make(chan urlStatus, 10)` without the go routine you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of this line

```
go consumer(future(), done)
```

When future() is called, the main go routine is blocked by wg.Wait()

Comment: you did not explain the reason. but I think I understand why now. because unbuffered channel  both sending and retrieving data are blocking.  the checker method sends the data to channel and wait for consumption but my async consumer only starts consuming when waitGrounp is down to 0. since the checker blocked on sending the `defer wg.Done()` never was executed.  so the `wg.Wait()` will block forever.  but if I put  `wg.Wait()`  in the goroutine the channel will be returned to my consumer goroutine which unblocks the checkUrl method. so the `defer wg.Done()` will have the opportunity to run

Comment: @Coronavirus I wrote the thing the above comment when explaining what you missed